# Segmentation fault when trying to printf() a char[] from a struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I am about a week into my C journey so please bear with me if this is a very silly question. I've done a basic course in C but have come up to pointers, so I am trying to write a little something that will help me understand. I have the following struct defined:

```
typedef struct {

    char room_ID;
    char room_exits[4];
    char room_description[255];

} Room;
```

I am then initialising this as a player_room variable

```
int main(){

    Room *player_Room = (Room*)malloc(sizeof(Room));
    player_Room->room_ID = '0';
    strcpy(player_Room->room_description, "There is an ogre in the room");
    strcpy(player_Room->room_exits, "N...");

    printf("%s ", player_Room->room_ID);
    printf(" %s", player_Room->room_description);

    return 0;
}
```

A segmentation fault occurs when debugging the code on the first printf() line above. I understand this is something of an access violation (I used to be a Delphi developer so I am used to those) trying to access memory to which my program has no access, or so I believe. It all compiles ok, just errors on that line

Once again, apologies if I am doing something stupid (I probably am) but I am very much a beginner just playing around with code trying to understand. Thanks in advance!

This is the first version of everything I have tried that has actually compiled, so I am a bit clueless as to where to go from here

Comment: Review `strcpy(player_Room->room_exits, "N...");`.  Trying to put a size 5 _string_ into a size 4 array.

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/11082165). GCC emits warnings for the problem here.

Comment: `printf("%s ", player_Room->room_ID);` but you have `char room_ID;`. You should use `"%c "`

Comment: Think carefully about what `printf("%s ", player_Room->room_ID);` is trying to do. What is the type of the second argument? What type does the `%s` format specifier expect, and what happens when the second argument is converted to and interpreted as that type? Do you know what is meant by null-terminated strings in C?

Comment: Unlrelated: I know this is C and you are going to `malloc` a lot - but then `free` just as much. In this case, `Room *player_Room = (Room*)malloc(sizeof(Room));` is totally unnecessary. Just make it an automatic variable: `Room player_Room;` and let it get destructed at the end of the scope.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses, I had forgotten about null terminated strings of course (the array is now 5) and altering my printf() to use %c instead of %s (which it should be of course as its a single char) has cleared the problem! Very many thanks to all of you for your replies (I will also enable compiler warnings thank you). Very much appreciated!

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you also for the advice - in this case I want to pass the room around several functions, so thought a pointer would be better?

Comment: That sounds right for the purpose. I just get itches when I see a `malloc` without a matching `free`.

Comment: Thank you @TedLyngmo - adding the free just now !